# In swift, how to access methods of class A inside class B if class B inherits from class A?

Tags: swift, unit-testing

Examples for creating mocked classes, methods and protocols would be helpful.

Comment: Using the 'super' keyword. Example: super.functionName()

Comment: I haven't come across the usage of "super" keyword in Swift programming language.

Comment: Then read this first: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was answered dozen of times. Here's the extract from one of the answers I gave on equivalent topic, slightly adjusted.

When you have class **B** derived from class **A**...

```
class ClassA: UIViewController {
    func myFunc() { print("...") }
}

class ClassB: ClassA {

}
```

In class **B**, you can call a method from class **A** by typing

```
super.myFunc() **OR** self.myFunc()
```

...depending on whether or not you have re-implemented that method in a subclass with `override` keyword.  If you **did not** `override` it (and you don't necessarily have to), then those two calls are equivalent.

On the other hand, if you added your own implementation in **B**:

```
override func myFunc() {
    print("My implementation of myFunc")
}
```

calling `super.myFunc()` will call implementation from **A**. And calling `self.myFunc()` will call your local implementation, both being acceptable from your subclass. And when your subclass calls `super` as well:

```
override func myFunc() {
    super.myFunc()
    print("My implementation of myFunc")
}
```

calling `self.myFunc()` from subclass will call implementation from both. Keep in mind, that if you don't call superclass implementation in your `override` method, you replace this implementation.

In most `UI`-classes, it's highly recommended to call superclass method upon overriding, in order to avoid any abnormal behavior, unless you provide sufficient implementation on your own (e.g. reposition or draw elements).

P.S. Mocks and unit-testing is the entire solid topic, simply impossible to cover in single post. Please, learn!